# PHP: die when is inserted the same value to table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have simple code where value is INSERTED when is not in table already and

I tried to make code where when value is not INSERTED to table script die or make another action to show for example 'value is already inserted' but my code doesnt work. Script only add value when is not in table and when value is in table add value and script continues to make AJAX request. Maybe when ajax done (value is add to table) and ajax fail (values is not add) and make some another irrelevant things.

```
$emaildb = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "dbdbdb");

if($emaildb === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($emaildb, $_REQUEST['email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email)
        SELECT '$email'
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT 1
            FROM emails
            WHERE email = '$email')
        LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($emaildb, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    if (isset($row->blocked)) {
        die('Denied!');
    } else {
        echo 'Access!';
    }
}

mysqli_close($emaildb);
```

Comment: Split your query into 2 parts. First do a select and then if the select returns no results perform the insert.

Comment: Dharman can u help with it plz?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_insert_id that will return 0 if nothing got inserted:

```
<?php

$emaildb = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "dbdbdb");

if(!$emaildb) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($emaildb, $_REQUEST['email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email)
        SELECT '$email'
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT 1
            FROM emails
            WHERE email = '$email')
        LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($emaildb, $sql);
if(mysqli_insert_id($emaildb) == 0) {
    echo "DIE!";
} else {
    echo "Access";
}

mysqli_close($emaildb);
```

Comment: and when I need to when value is not inserted to table do another ajax or in ajax do in fail ajax?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

A proper SELECT and INSERT scenario like yours would look something like this:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // enable exception mode
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "test");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    throw new \Exception("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    $selectStmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM emails WHERE email=?');
    $selectStmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['email']);
    $selectStmt->execute();
    $found = $selectStmt->get_result()->fetch_array()[0];
    if ($found) {
        echo 'This email already exists!';
    } else {
        $insertStmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES (?)');
        $insertStmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['email']);
        $insertStmt->execute();

        echo 'Email has been added';
    }
}
```

I have used prepared statements and executed two separate queries. To make like simpler I have also enabled MySQLi exception mode.
This code will first check if the email exists in DB, and if it doesn't it will try to insert it. Try to avoid `die()`-ing in your code, it is never a good practice to do so.

This code example is without AJAX. You need to adapt this to your particular application and implement some error checking. This code is only to show the recommended way of executing SQL statements.